# SwiftUI update a list with socket payload

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io, swiftui, combine

I am newer to SwiftUI and am not sure how I should architect my app.

I am building a stocks app that will display a list of stocks and I am wanting to use SocketIO to connect to my backend to update the stocks list with real-time prices.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import Combine
import SocketIO
import SwiftUI

struct RealtimePriceResponse: Codable {
    let quotes: [RealtimeQuote]
}

struct RealtimeQuote: Codable {
    let ticker, last, previousClose: String?
}


class SocketConnection: ObservableObject {
    @Published var realtimeQuotes: [RealtimeQuote] = []
    @Published var isConnected: Bool = false
    
    let socketManager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "https://api.myapp.com")!, config: [.log(true), .compress])
    var socket: SocketIO.SocketIOClient

    init(tickers: [String]) {
        socket = socketManager.defaultSocket
        socket.connect()
        
        socket.on(clientEvent: .connect) { data, ack in
            self.isConnected = true
            print("Socket has connected")
            self.socket.emit("priceListen", ["userId": "121212", "symbols": tickers])
        }

        socket.on("userid") { [unowned self]  data, ack in
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: data[0])
            let priceUpdates = try? decoder.decode(RealtimePriceResponse.self, from: jsonData!)
            if let decoded = priceUpdates {
                self.realtimeQuotes = decoded.quotes
                print("Real-time Prices: \(String(describing: decoded))")
            }
        }
        
        socket.on(clientEvent: .disconnect) { data, ack in
            self.isConnected = false
            print("Socket has disconnected")
        }
    }
}

struct StocksView: View {
    var tickers: [String] = ["TSLA", "SNAP", "DIS", "AMZN"]
    
    @ObservedObject var socket: SocketConnection
    
    init() {
        self.socket = SocketConnection(tickers: self.tickers)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        return List(tickers, id: \.self) { ticker in
            Stock(ticker: ticker, quote: self.socket.realtimeQuotes.first(where: { $0.ticker == ticker }) ?? RealtimeQuote?.none)
        }
    }
}

struct Stock: View {
    var ticker: String
    var price: String
    
    init(ticker: String, quote: RealtimeQuote?) {
        self.ticker = ticker
        if let quote = quote {
            price = quote.last!
        } else {
            self.price = "--.--"
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(ticker).bold()
            Spacer()
            Text("$\(price)")
        }
    }
}
```

This does not work as I would expect it to. Should my view hold onto an instance of this SocketConnection class? That seems risky and not the best way. Also, how should I update just the Text() view in the HStack that holds the price?

Answer (score 0):

Make the `SocketConnection` and `ObservableObject` and it's instance and `ObservedObject`.

```
class SocketConnection: ObservableObject {
    //...
}
//...
struct StocksView: View {
    //...
    @ObservedObject var homeSocket: SocketConnection
    //...
}
```

Comment: I updated my code in the question to use what you recommended and it does not work as I expected.

Comment: You're still making a new instance of the `SocketConnection` object every time the view is refreshed/recreated. Delete your custom `init` in`SocketView`. Make only one SocketConnection object and pass that to the view.